# Unity Banner Real Ads Not Showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, banner-ads, unityads

Hi please help me why unity real banner Ads not Show in My App Test Ads Also Show But Real Banner Ads Not Showing.

Other Country Like United States Show Banner Ads Properly but India not showing.

Comment: Show your code for banner ad and also show logcat logs to better understand your problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check and make sure banner ads is active in unity dashboard